# How can I know if some method has called that has a specific attribute in c#

Tags: c#, methods, attributes

```
class SampleClass 
{
    [SampleAttribute]
    public void SampleMethod() 
    {
        
    }
}
```

If there is a method like the above code. How can I know the method has called that has a specific attribute(*In this case the attribute is 'SampleAttribute'*)? I know how to find methods that have specific attributes. But I don't know how to figure out when the method has called that has a specific attribute

Comment: Just so I'm clear: you want to know if the method that *called your method* has an attribute? That ultimately becomes the problem of "find which method has called the current method", which *can be done* (at least sort-of, not accounting for inlining), but: it isn't *efficient*. Can you perhaps give more context as to what you're *actually trying to achieve* (rather than how you're trying to achieve it), as: there may be great alternatives that you haven't considered

Comment: You mean how the caller of the method know if this method has a specific attribute? Example this method is called as `sa.SampleMethod()` in Main method then how the `Main` method will know if `SampleMethod` has specific attribute..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a few ways. But first, let's add some value to the SampleAttribute, to be sure, that everything is working:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SampleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SampleAttribute(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }

    public string Text { get; private set; }
}
```

And specify the attribute value to the method:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    [SampleAttribute("This is attribute text")]
    public void SampleMethod() { }
}
```

Now, using the reflection mechanism, we can extract the attribute value from the object:

```
var sampleClass = new SampleClass();
ExtractSampleAttributeValue(sampleClass);

private static string ExtractSampleAttributeValue(SampleClass sampleClass)
{
        var methods = sampleClass.GetType().GetMethods();
        var sampleMethod = methods.FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name == nameof(sampleClass.SampleMethod));
        var sampleAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(sampleMethod, typeof(SampleAttribute)) as SampleAttribute;
        return sampleAttribute.Text;
}
```

Or even pass the method as the parameter:

```
var sampleClass = new SampleClass();
ExtractSampleAttributeValue(sampleClass.SampleMethod);

 private static string ExtractSampleAttributeValue(Action sampleMethod)
 {
        var sampleAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(sampleMethod.Method, typeof(SampleAttribute)) as SampleAttribute;
        return sampleAttribute.Text;
 }
```